# How to generate plessy barcode and print from my application

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-printing

I am new android developer. I don't know how to create barcode generate application.
In this application when I put some no in textbox and click on print button then barcode will print from barcode machine and barcode number print below this barcode.

Comment: This question is too broad. Did you write any code yet? Did you do any research yet? Or do you want us to do your work? See the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask article

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best choice is the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library. You can create almost every kind of barcode imaginable. You can generate pdfs (so vectorized images) and save and print them.